# How to write tar stream entry with unknown size?

Tags: node.js, tar, zlib

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
import * as Path from 'path'
import {exportTableDataToFile} from '../struct'
import * as Tar from 'tar-stream'
import * as Zlib from 'zlib'
import * as FileSys from 'fs'

async function execute(opts, args) {
    const pack = Tar.pack()

    pack.pipe(Zlib.createGzip({level: Zlib.constants.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION})).pipe(FileSys.createWriteStream(opts.file))

    const tblDataFile = Path.join(db.name, `${tblName}.csv`)
    const dataStream = pack.entry({name: tblDataFile}, err => {
        if(err) throw err;
    })
    await exportTableDataToFile(conn, db.name, tblName, dataStream)
}
```

Where `exportTableDataToFile` is writing a CSV into `dataStream` line-by-line.

Since I'm generating that CSV on the fly from some database records, I don't know how big it's going to be.

I also don't really want buffer the entire CSV into memory if I can help it.

The above is throwing ["size mismatch"](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-stream/blob/e08fcd845744c43e1e71343f117be9993208103a/pack.js#L175) because I didn't specify the size in `pack.entry(...)`

Is there any way I can stream to a `.tar.gz` in Node.js without knowing the size?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some module, if you just want to create a CSV from DB of an unknown size you can do the same as below:

```
const fs = require("fs");

const csvFile = fs.createWriteStream("db.csv");
//column headers of your csv, remove if not needed
csvFile.write("column1, column2, column3, column4");

while(true){
  const result=db.find(table);//db call -> replace it with your db fetch call
  //Here I am expecting column1Value ... to be the field in my DB
  for(const elem of result){
    csvFile.write(`${elem.column1Value}, ${elem.column2Value}, ${elem.column3Value}, ${elem.column4Value}`);
  }
  if(!result.length){
    break
  }
//Need to handle pagination

}
```

you can replace DB call as per your syntax.

Comment: Yeah.. I wrote a class similar to that, the problem is streaming it into a `.tar` file without first writing it to disk or buffering the entire thing into memory.

Comment: You can save CSV to the disk first, and then create .tar from it. The size of the file would also be there then.